# Generic methods with duplicate signature

Tags: c#, generics, overloading, method-signature

I have these two method-signatures:

```
protected object HandleRequest<TResponse, TRequest>(Func<TRequest, TResponse> func, TRequest request)
    where TResponse : BaseResponse
    where TRequest : BaseRequest
```

and

```
protected object HandleRequest<TResponse, TController>(Func<TController, TResponse> func, TController controller)
    where TResponse : BaseResponse
    where TController : MasterController
```

I get the following build-error: `'...' already defines a member called 'HandleRequest' with the same parameter types`.

Why do I get this error and how can it be solved?

Comment: Unfortunately the type constraints aren't part of the method signature. See Eric Lippert's blog http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/12/10/constraints-are-not-part-of-the-signature.aspx That means the only way to solve it would be to have the two methods differ in a way in addition to the type constraints.

Answer (score 0):

You can't overload methods just by using different constraints. C# is not so optimistic about resolving ambiguity as ie. C++. You need to give it other name or change signature.